# Transaction failing while transferring NFT on solana: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1

Tags: blockchain, solana, nft, solana-program-library

Error: Failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1.
Getting this error when transferring the NFT token. After looking up the error code 0x1 from [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/ea354ab358021aa08f774e2d4028b33ec56d4180/token/program/src/error.rs#L16), got to know that the error is due to insufficient funds in the sender account. But I have some 8 SOL which I guess should be enough for the transaction.

I am implementing the transfer NFT logic using the first answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70224185/how-to-transfer-custom-spl-token-by-solana-web3-js-and-solana-sol-wallet-ad)

What am I missing here?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I can help more if you specify the code you wrote. But I guess the balance of the account you sent may be low (or zero), so you need to send NFT with fund-recipient.

If the receiver does not yet have an associated token account, the sender need to fund to create associated token account for receiver's solana account.

I usually create associated token account (here you need to create it for your NFT account for recipient) then transfer token or NFT

for python coding

```
token_pda_address = get_associated_token_address(sender_account, mint_account)

mint_account = get_associated_token_address(destination_account, mint_account)

associated_token_account = create_associated_token_account_instruction(
    associated_token_account=mint_account,
    payer=source_account.public_key,  # signer
    wallet_address=destination_account,
    token_mint_address=mint_account,
)

spl_transfer = spl_transfer(
    SPLTransferParams(
        program_id=token_account,
        source=token_pda_address,
        dest=associated_token_account,
        owner=sender_account,
        signers=[],
        amount=1,
)
```

in this example `token_pda_address` and `associated_token_account` must be the same type of account.